# Is Classical least squares the most efficient way to estimate?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, estimation, least-squares

Suppose we believed that the relationship between individual stock prices and dividend payments satisfied the assumptions of the classical linear regression model (with the Gauss Markov assumptions) for observations drawn across different stocks and/or across different time periods. However, the only data available to you are group averages of stock prices and dividend payments for a group of 500 industrial firms, collected over 43 years. Is classical least squares the most efficient way to estimate the regression coefficients using these group-averaged variables?