# Durbin watson value

Tags: mathematical-statistics, estimation, least-squares

Is it true that in a time-series regression of $Y_t$ on six exogenous regressors (including the intercept) and $T = 207$ observations, a Durbin-Watson value of $DV = 1.98$ would yield rejection of the null hypothesis of no first-order serial correlation, indicating that the usual least-squares estimator and its standard errors will be inconsistent and that the generalized least-squares estimator would be more efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Durbin-Watson statistics around 2 means NO correlation at all](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durbin%E2%80%93Watson_statistic#Computing_and_interpreting_the_Durbin.E2.80.93Watson_statistic). Therefore, with 1.98 (nearly 2) you don't reject the null hypothesis of no first-order serial correlation.

With 200 observation and 6 exogenous regressors, critical value is [about 1.71.](http://berument.bilkent.edu.tr/DW.pdf)

Comment: Hi, could you also take a look at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/249854/is-classical-least-squares-the-most-efficient-way-to-estimate? Thank you very much!